# Power loss while updating arch linux, can't boot into OS anymore

Tags: arch-linux, dual-boot, boot-loader

I've installed Arch Linux a couple of days ago and am slowly migrating to that from Windows, after 15 years of Windows-only desktops.

Today I wanted to start playing some games and get proper AMD graphics drivers. When installing radeon vulkan drivers, the source returned a 404 error, so I couldn't download them. Thought that maybe I should sync my AUR repos. So, I ran and update anything I've installed in past couple of days with:

```
yaourt -Syu --devel --aur
```

While system was updating, I lost power.

---

Now, whenever I try starting up Arch, shows these errors:

```
[FAILED] Failed to start Load Kernel Modules.
[..]
[FAILED] Failed to mount boot.
[DEPEND] Dependency failed for Local File Systems.
```

And then goes into emergency mode.

---

Getting status from `systemd-modules-load` includes:

```
Failed to lookup alias 'crpyto_user' : Function not implemented
Failed to lookup alias 'sg' : Function not implemented
-modules-load.service: Failed with result 'exit-code' to start Load Kernel Modules
```

And status from mount included something about 'phat' not being known file system.

---

Any advice on how to fix this?

Answer (score 3):

First, **stop using yaourt for package management**: it is an AUR Helper, and [a bad one](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/AUR_helpers#Discontinued_or_problematic) at that. Use pacman for your package management tasks, that is its job.

To recover from an incomplete upgrade, there is a procedure [documented on the wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Pacman#Pacman_crashes_during_an_upgrade). Essentially, boot from the live medium and, after having mounted all of the filesystems, run the upgrade again using the `--root` flag:

```
pacman --root=/mnt --cachedir=/mnt/var/cache/pacman/pkg -Syyu
```

Then check for any incomplete files before exiting and rebooting.

Comment: I agree yaourt is bad but the AUR has lots of useful stuff and it's also bad to not have a manager for that.